# Show playing song of Last.fm in the sound notification panel

Tags: notification-area, last.fm-client

When I use Rhythmbox, I see the currently played song in the sound notification area, is there some way to get the song that is playing on last.fm there?

I currently use the official last.fm program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say for the official Last.FM player, but I know that Tagplayer (a very popular dedicated last.fm player) supports this. Also Rhythmbox has a last.fm plugin by default. Playing last.fm streams through that should also use the sound menu.

Comment: Indeed, both Rhythmbox and Banshee support that.