# Last.FM indicator/notification support

Tags: last.fm-client

Is it possible to enable indicator/notification support for the LastFM client? Is there a plug-in or PPA for this?
If not, is this support being worked on?

As an aside, is the LastFM client open-source... can the community work on this?

Comment: Also asked for here http://askubuntu.com/questions/34436/show-playing-song-of-last-fm-in-the-sound-notification-panel

Comment: So the answer it appears is "no", at least for now. Whether the last.fm client is open-source or indicator/notification support is being worked on, remain open questions.

Comment: Hmm guess so. Used to have this in meego and it was really good , liek a twitter feed but my mates 'sounds!'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible at all. Additionally, if using the last.fm client with Unity you may experiences [some oddities](http://www.last.fm/forum/34905/_/684752).

The last.fm client is open source and con be downloaded by running `svn checkout svn://svn.audioscrobbler.net/clientside/Last.fm` in a terminal window.

Whether or not "the community" is wokring on addressing this depends on whether anyone is interested in addressing it. So, either encourage someone you know to work on it, grab the code yourself and work on it, or raise this issue on the [last.fm support forum](http://www.last.fm/forum/34905).